# I'm not able to print node evaluation results in python. My results are visible in VISSIM but can't access them through API COM

Tags: python, ptv-vissim

I'm writing a program and need to get the following Node results:- ["fuel consumption, Emissions CO, NOx, VOC"] as shown in image. I just need to print these results in Python. My results are visible in VISSIM but can't access them through COM.

[image]

I couldn't find any help in PTV Vissim\Training Examples\Basic Commands.

I've tried using multiple codes but It's not working. eg.

1. `Vissim.Net.Nodes.Attvalue('FuelConsumption(Avg,Avg))`
2. `Vissim.Net.Node.Movements.ItemBykey(1).AttValue(FuelConsumption(Avg,Avg))`
3. `Vissim.Net.Movements.ItemByKey(1).AttValue(FuelConsumption(Avg,Avg))`
4. `Vissim.Net.Nodes.Attvalue('EmissionsCO(Avg,Avg))` etc.

I have used COM HELP to write the above syntax but it's giving an error.
I don't want user defined emissions. In Vissim, if you go to **evaluation\Results List\Node Results**: A list opens which gives by default values of Emissions and fuel consumption. I just need to print those values in EXCEL using PYTHON.

Comment: Most of the Vissim community exchanges happens on LinkedIn (https://www.linkedin.com/groups/2524087). So you might get faster answers there. Or you could also contact PTV's technical support.

Answer (score 0):

How about saving the result after simulation, close Vissim and then read .att file? I do this job with Ling Segment Results and Node Results.

Here is my simple code: (Python3.7, Vissim 2020)

```
network_filename, _extention = datainfo['vissim_inpx'].split('.')

node_result = f'{network_filename}_Node Results_001.att'
cal.extract_from_node(node_result)
```

You have to click 'Autosave after simulation' button in advance to successfully get 'Node Results_001.att'.

Hope this helps.